# OOP: How to "know" the object's type in this game design

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Let's image for a game, I have this scheme

`Item` is what all the game's Item based off

Some `Item` like `Sword` implements `IEquipable`

Some `Item` like `Potion` implements `IConsumable`

When I am giving out a quest reward, I add an `Item` to the character.
When I am listing out the character's inventory, I go through their `List` of `Item`. At this time, I only know I have some `Item` but no longer know that the Item is `Equipable` or `Consumable` . Basically, the Interface is no longer known to me. What design can I do in this circumstance?

Let's be more specific.

When an Item is `IConsumable`, I would like them to "stack" on top of eachother, may be give a different glow to them and a right-click action will result in consuming that item

When an Item is `IEquipable`, The item will not stack inside the inventory, may be give a different glow to them and a right-click action will result in equipping that item

Should I do type-checking (If item is IEquipable then -> Do IEquipable-specific actions or access specific property). Or maybe there would be a different design altogether for this type of problem?

I am looking for answer that describe if this is not a problem or how I can avoid it if is a design problem (of needing to access to feature of more "refined" class while what we have at hand is the more generic class) - with example if possible

Update: I would argue that it makes sense for inventory to be basing off `Item`. While Item provides the most basic functionality like `Name`, `GoldValue` or `ItemIcon`.

Though properties like `Durability` or `Enchantments[]` can only be applied to Equipables. Let's take a look at Minecraft inventory. I would say every basic interaction are from `InventorySystem` to `Item`. Though it is still necessary to know what is the kind of `Item` the `InventorySystem` is processing? Like `Bread` , what I see is that they are consumables and can stack up to 64 in one single slot

[image]

Comment: From the naming convention it seems that you are using C#. The easiest thing you can do is 'foreach(var item in inventory) { if (item is IEquipable) { .... } else if (item is IConsumable) { .... } }'. There could be more elegant solutions, if you share exactly what you need to do

Comment: Hey I recomend to take off the design-patterns tag, I think this is un-related... Also if you used here a design-pattern it is not an integral part of the question. I think the last comment is the answer

Comment: Thanks @ddfra At first I did not think type check was the only solution. Eitherway, can you help me put it as an answer? I think I'll choose it as the solution

Comment: @qkhanhpro might you want to add c# as a tag?

Comment: @qkhanhpro I edited my response and added a solution that uses the visitor pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the `is` keyword will do what you're describing, but I think it would be better to change your approach to the problem.

I'm going to ignore the "stacking" part of your question because I don't know what "stacking" means here--is it a visual stacking on-screen, or is it a logical combination of different items in the rules of the game? I think my answer will be clear enough using just the glow effect and consume/equip actions. If so, you should be able to connect the dots to implement stacking yourself.

The `is` and `as` keywords and the Linq `OfType<T>()` extension method are all simple ways to do the type-checking you described. They allow some sort of central game manager or player class (I'll just say "game manager" from now on) to ask each `Item` what its type is and then make decisions based on the response. The approach will work for simple systems, but might become difficult to maintain as the number of `Item` types grows--the game manager needs to know about the quirks of every `Item` type.

*Edit 1:* It's also worth noting that type-checking is generally assumed to perform poorly. I say "generally assumed" because the only way to know for sure whether something is performant enough for a given situation is to write and test the code--but I would personally avoid doing any type-checking in a game's update or draw loop.

Instead, consider adding new properties or methods to `Item`: perhaps a `GlowEffect` property, and `Use` method. These methods would allow the game manager to ask the `Item` what to do or notify the `Item` that something has happened in the game. The game manager no longer needs to know about every possible `Item` type or its behavior--the behavior is encapsulated in the `Item` itself. You might not even need the `IEquippable` and `IConsumable` interfaces anymore.

I would characterize this as a "strategy" design pattern. Each `Item` implementation contains strategies for how to display or interact with a specific in-game resource or tool.

```cs
public abstract class Item : Item
{
    public abstract GlowEffect GlowEffect { get; }

    // A reference to the current Player allows the "Use"
    // method to affect the active player.
    public abstract void Use(Player player);
}
```

```cs
public class Sword
{
    public override GlowEffect GlowEffect { get { return new GreenGlowEffect(); } }

    public override void Use(Player player)
    {
        player.Equip(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can use the `is` keyword to check whether an object is an instance of a certain class/interface. Therefore you can do:

```
 foreach (var item in inventory)
 {
     if (item is IEquipable)
     {
         IEquipable equipable = item as IEquipable;
         //....
     }
     else if (item is IConsumable)
     {
         IConsumable consumable = item as IConsumable;
         //....
     }
 }
```

EDIT

If you want to use a structured pattern rather than an if else the following can help you. I personally think that in your case adds a lot of complexity that you can avoid.

let's start from the IItem interface. We'll let IConsumable and IEquipable inherit from it. We put the foundation of a Visitor pattern here that will be helpful later

```
 interface IItem {
      void Accept(IItemVisitor visitor);
 }
 interface IConsumable: IItem {}
 interface IEquipable: IItem {}

 interface IItemVisitor {
      void Visit(IConsumable consumable);
      void Visit(IEquipable equipable);
 }

 abstract class ConsumableBase: IConsumable
 {
      void Accept(IItemVisitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
 }


 abstract class EquipableBase: IEquipable
 {
      void Accept(IItemVisitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
 }
```

the visitor pattern is what will avoid that if/else of the previous solution.

Now I assume you have an InventoryManager class where you populate the Inventory given a list of items. It might look like the following:

```
 class InventoryManager : IItemVisitor
 {
       void PopulateInventory(IEnumerable<IItem> items)
       {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                 item.Accept(this);
            }
       }
       void Visit(IEquipable equipable)
       {
            //add equipable to the inventory
       }
       void Visit(IConsumable consumable)
       {
            //add consumable to the inventory
       } 
  }
```

This is the best pattern you can use when have to deal with different branches of the inheritance tree but you cannot solve with polymorphism directly.
It has some drawbacks, for instance if you add a new interface that extends IItem you need to change all the visitor classes. It also adds some complexity to the code, so it's probably not worth the effort in some cases.
Anyway, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: You can reduce the syntactic boiler plate even more with a [declaration pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns)  such as  `if(item is IEquipable equipable){ // ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here.

> `Item` is what all the game's Item based off

A fundamental misconception when entering the realm of OOP is that an application is built by creating a single object hierarchy with one (business) object at its root. This will cause you nothing but pain. Abstractions must be based upon common behaviors: objects which can be used in the same way. Every non-trivial application will have numerous object hierarchies. If you find yourself with an abstraction you cannot use, then you have created the wrong abstraction.

Here is how I suggest interpreting the problem statement above.

> 1. I have put all of my objects into a bag where I cannot tell the difference between them.
> 2. I need to tell the difference between them.

Hopefully the answer is obvious. *Don't put your objects into that bag!* Eliminate the `Item` abstraction and don't treat objects as abstractions you can't use. Of course, designing the *right* abstraction is hard. There's no way around that, and the abstractions that are right for your application won't necessarily be the same for any other application.

Regarding other answers,

- Type checking is a valid solution in procedural programming or functional programming. It is not an object-oriented solution. And that's fine. You don't have to do OOP.
- Visitor Pattern is a complex, niche solution for a small, fixed object hierarchy. It is not a pattern to base an application on. A different programming paradigm would be more appropriate.

Now, what every developer who faces this problem wants to hear is, what is the solution? You're going to be disappointed, because I can't tell you. No one can. Consider what you're asking. There is essentially no difference between this question and, "*How should I design an Object-Oriented application?*" Providing a domain like "game" and naming a handful of domain objects does nothing to change the question. Entire books are written to answer this question.

If you want to learn by coding, all you can do is try different abstractions. If that doesn't work, you can try non-OO solutions. If that doesn't work you will have learned something. At this stage of development, implementing the the wrong solution and learning from it is more valuable than implementing the right solution without understanding tradeoffs.

Comment: Yeah, but.... Player inventories are often just a bag of items.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular scenario, I suggest you separate the items at the moment of adding them to the character.
You can use several overloads and the compiler will do the job for you...

```
public class Character {
    ...
    List<Item> Items {get;} = new List<Item>();
    List<Item> ConsumableItems {get;} = new List<Item>();
    List<Item> EquipableItems {get;} = new List<Item>();
    public void AddItem(IEquipable item) {
      Items.Add(item); EquipableItems.Add(item);
    }
    public void AddItem(IConsumable item) {
      Items.Add(item); ConsumableItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

In case handling separated lists is not working for you, adding an ItemType field for the Item class would simplify things.

```
 enum ItemType { Equipable, Consumable }

 // usage example
 public class SomeConsumableItem : IConsumable {

  public readonly ItemType ItemType {get;} = ItemType.Consumable;
  ...
 }
```