# How to solve generic ingredients problem without typechecks?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, typechecking

I couldn't find anything on this problem online so I'm going to try to explain it as clear as possible.

I have a class with a generic list containing ingredients:

```cs
class Inventory{
    List<Ingredient> ingredients;
}

abstract class Ingredient{
    int amount;
}

class Flour : Ingredient{}

class Egg : Ingredient{}
```

I also have a recipe that needs a certain amount of these ingredients:

```cs
class Recipe{
    //this could be a dictionary or whatever
    int requiredFlour = 20;
    int requiredEgg = 3;

    bool canBeMade(Inventory i){}
}
```

I need to check if the inventory has enough ingredients to make the recipe.
Is there any solution to this without typechecking the ingredients?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "without typechecking the ingredients". I presume you don't want to ask each ingredient its type. How about having a "CheckRecipe" object and pass to every ingredient in the list. The ingredient would subtract its quantity, if it was listed. In the end you'd have to check if all quantities are zero. But you'd still need a notion of "ingredient type", otherwise the recipe and the ingredients won't be able to communicate.

Comment: I think this question is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69235748/oop-how-to-know-the-objects-type-in-this-game-design

Comment: @jaco0646, while that post is somewhat similar, it can be solved easily with visitor pattern. That is not the case in my question, or at least I don't see how that would work.

Comment: I think Visitor may be a poor solution in either case; but what do you see as the critical difference between this list of ingredients and that list of items?