# Trying to implement composition with a variable number and type of components

Tags: oop, design-patterns, game-development, composition

I'm trying to implement composition as the design pattern for an item system. For example, I have a base `item` class, and it has a name and an ID. But some items are equippable, and instead of making an `equippable_item` class that inherits from the `item` class, I want the `item` to have a reference to an `equippable` widget. But not every `item` is equippable, and I'm not going to make a specific class with the specific widgets needed for each item, as you would in a typical composition example.

So instead of having a direct reference to the specific widgets in a bunch of classes, I keep the base `item` class and make a base `widget` interface, and have the `item` store a list of `widget`s. Now I can have other `widget`s that detail other behaviour or statistics about the item, and I can mix and match them variably as I define `item`s.

Here is where I'm stuck - first of all, is this the right approach to achieving the behaviour I want?

If this is the right approach, when I pull up an item and all the item has is a list of interface `widget`s, how will I know what concrete sub-types of `widget` it has?

If I have to determine the sub-type of each `widget` and then do specific things with it based on that, what was the point of abstracting the widgets in the first place?

I'm sorry if these questions are too broad, but hopefully someone out there has some experience with making a system like this - I'm not sure what to call it, maybe variable composition? Is this even a thing? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: related: [OOP: How to "know" the object's type in this game design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69235748/1371329)

Comment: @jaco0646 Thanks, I had a look at the answers there but it's not quite the same problem I'm having